# RequireJS - jquery dependencies & priority

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I've been using RequireJS for quite a while now, but I recently ran across something I've never seen before.

I have a simple page that will use SelectBoxIt and Caroufredsel.  Caroufredsel requires jQuery.  But SelectBoxIt requires jQueryUI (actually just the widget factory) which requires jQuery.

I was under the impression that the way to set up these dependencies was to use the require.config shim like so:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery" : [
            "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min",
            "libs/jquery-1.8.2.min"
        ],

        jqueryui :    "libs/jquery.ui.widget",
        selectboxit : "libs/jquery.selectBoxIt.min",
        caroufredsel: "libs/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed"

    },
    shim:{
        jqueryui:       ['jquery'],
        selectboxit:    ['jqueryui'],
        caroufredsel:   ['jquery']
    }
});
```

This, however, generates cascading errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.ui.widget.js:528
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js:4
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js:16
```

Someone then told me about the priority property of the config object:

```
requirejs.config({
    priority: ["libs/jquery-1.8.2.min"],
    paths: {
        "jquery" : [
            "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min"
          ,  "libs/jquery-1.8.2.min"
        ]

        , jqueryui :    "libs/jquery.ui.widget"
        , selectboxit : "libs/jquery.selectBoxIt.min"
        , caroufredsel: "libs/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed"

    },
    shim:{  // update, removed jquery as it doesn't need shim
        jqueryui:       ['jquery']
        , selectboxit:    ['jqueryui']
        , caroufredsel:   ['jquery']
    }
});
```

Everyone is happy with this in place but something doesn't feel right.  I would have thought that the string to place in the priority property would be "jquery" which would resolve to either the CDN version or the local version.

But this caused a new error:

```
GET http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min,libs/jquery-1.8.2.min.js 404 (Not Found)
```

But by having to choose which to place in the priority property aren't I defeating the purpose of putting in two items in the jquery placeholder?

What am I missing?  And how have I not seen this problem before?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a big problem with what you are showing us, which *may* explain the problems you are experiencing:

- `priority` is a RequireJS 1.x option, not recognized by RequireJS 2.x.
- `shim` is a RequireJS 2.x option, not recognized by RequireJS 1.x.

If `priority` made a difference, this suggests you are using RequireJS 1.x and your shims are ignored. Also, jQuery 1.8.2 does not need a shim because it calls `define`.

Comment: Ha!  That's it.  I'm adding a page to an older site and didn't even consider they had used require 1.x!  And I removed the jquery shim from the question- that shouldn't have been in there.  Thanks!

Comment: Check out the article I wrote about using jQueryUI Widget Factory plugins with Require.js.  I even talk about using SelectBoxIt: http://gregfranko.com/blog/registering-the-jqueryui-widget-factory-as-an-amd-module/